# JLabel setLocation not working?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jlabel

Here is the code I have written:

```
super("Add contact");

setLayout(new FlowLayout());
IPAddress = new JLabel("IP Address");
IPAddress.setLocation(1000, 100);

ImageIcon ii=new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Add.png"));
JLabel image = new JLabel(ii);
image.setSize(100, 100);
image.setLocation(500, 100);
add(image);
add(IPAddress);
setSize(500,150);
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is correct. The layout manager is responsible for setting the location of a component based on the rules of the layout manager. So in your case the FlowLayout will override the location of the component.

You should never hardcode the location of a component. What if somebody is using resolution less then 1024 X 768? The component will never show.

You should also never set the size of a component. Every component has a preferred size. In the case of label with the image, the preferred size will be the size of the image.

Read up on [Layout Managers](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html) and use the appropriate layout manager or combination of layout managers to achieve your desired layout.